# intent filter for open .shtml attachmment fron the email...

Tags: android, android-intent

I am facing the problem in the scenario like::
 I have an activity to received an email, with attached shtml file .
 How to  open that attached file.

Or how can I handle this?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this attached to the Activity you want to handle the `Intent`.  AFAIK, the only way to handle a particular file extension is to use `pathPattern`, as I don't believe you can be guaranteed on how the mail application(s) will set the MIME type of a file they don't recognize.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.shtml" />
</intent-filter>
```

The email app bundled with the AOSP infers a MIME type from an attached file, so if it cannot find one in the static map, it will use `application/xxx`, so you might also try

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/shtml" />
</intent-filter>
```

The scheme attribute in both cases may be unnecessary or hindering if the mail app uses a different format (like content://), so if it doesn't work try omitting that piece.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's my latest iteration of getting an attachment from an email.  If you use it it would be cool if you kept my name with your source.

```
if (intentaction != null) {
        if (intentaction.equals("android.intent.action.VIEW")) {

            Uri data = intent.getData();
            Uri u;

            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    pathname = data.getPath();
                    File f = new File(pathname);
                    boolean b = f.exists();
                    if (!b) {
                        pathname = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    pathname = null;
                }
                if (pathname == null) {
                    try {
                        is = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver()
                                .openInputStream(data));
                        _is = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver()
                                .openInputStream(data));
                        // _savefile = true;
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(data, null, null,
                            null, null);
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.moveToFirst();
                        int fileNameColumnId = c
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        if (fileNameColumnId >= 0) {
                            _previewFileName = c
                                    .getString(fileNameColumnId);
                        }
                        if (_previewFileName == null) {
                            fileNameColumnId = c
                                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                            if (fileNameColumnId >= 0) {
                                pathname = c.getString(fileNameColumnId);
                                File f = new File(pathname);
                                boolean b = f.exists();
                                if (b) {
                                    try {
                                        if (is != null) {
                                            is.close();
                                        }
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    is = null;
                                    try {
                                        if (_is != null) {
                                            _is.close();
                                        }
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    _is = null;
                                } else {
                                    pathname = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If we have an attachment
    if (is != null) {
        k = new KmlSummary(is);
    } else if (pathname != null) {
        k = new KmlSummary(pathname);
```

Good Luck